# Question on convergence in the weak topology of measures

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $f_n \in W^{2,p}(\Gamma)$ ($\Gamma$ here is the $C^2-$regular boundary of a bounded, open and connected subset of $\mathbb R^3$) and suppose ${\vert \vert f_n \vert \vert}_{L^1} \le M \;\forall n$ for some positive constant $M$. I 'm trying to understand the following:

> There exist $f \in \mathcal M_{+}(\Gamma)$ such that $f_n \to f$
>   weakly. **The convergence of $\{f_n\}_n$ takes place in the weak
>   topology of measures.**

- Why does this weak convegence hold? I tried to find some weak convergence theorems in measure theory that relate somehow the $L^1-$boundedness but all I found was about probability measures which is not my case.

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me understand this implication. I had some measure theory courses in the past but we never mentioned weak convergence there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only expect a subsequence to converge weakly. The whole sequence need not converge: take $f_n=f$ for $n$ even, $g$ for $n$ odd with $f \neq g$. Convergence of a subsequence is a consequence of Banach -Alaoglu Theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But $L^1$ is not a dual space and the Banach-Alaoglu theorem is applied in dual spaces...right?

Comment: I am considering the space of measures as a dual of  aspace of continuous functions and applying B-A. If you consider your $f_n$'s as measures then their total variations are bounded by $1$ so they lie in the unit ball of the space of measures.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh I see...I think this now helped me! Thanks a lot

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy One more question please... Why are their total variations bounded by 1?